# How to get second value from input time html tag to JavaScript variable

Tags: javascript, html

s1 variable is not getting seconds value

```js
function fun()
{
    time=document.getElementById("time").value;
    h1=time[0];
    h2=time[1];
    m1=time[3];
    m2=time[4];
    s1=time[6];// Not Working 
    document.getElementById("print").value=h1+""+h2+""+":"+m1+""+m2+":"+s1;
}
setInterval(fun,1000);
```

```html
<p>Time:<p>
<input type="time" id="time" name="time" step="1"></input><br>
<input type="text" id="print"></input>
```

Comment: Are you sure the seconds value is defined?

Comment: You should probably take the text value and parse it as a date string. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/parse

Comment: @Alexander `step="1"` means the granularity is seconds, rather than the default minutes granularity. If you run the snippet you'll see a seconds field.

Comment: Why do you think it's not working? If I enter `01:02:56 AM`, `time[6]` correctly shows as `5`.

Comment: If you want both digits of the seconds, you need `time[6]` and `time[7]`.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you want?

```js
function fun()
{
time=document.getElementById("time").value;
h1=time[0];
h2=time[1];
m1=time[3];
m2=time[4];
s1=time[6];
s2=time[7];
document.getElementById("print").value = h1+""+h2+""+":"+m1+""+m2+":"+s1+""+s2;
}
```

```html
<p>Time:</p><input type="time" id="time" name="time" step="1"></input><br>
<input type="text" id="print"></input>
```

Comment: I assume the second  `<p>` tag is just a 2nd paragraph, wrapping the inputs.

Comment: `<p>` does not need to be closed, as is `<li>`. The next `<p>` closes the previous one.

Comment: No problem, I even prefer to close it, but you pointed this out as if it was a mistake.

Comment: I am sorry. Now I had edited my answer as well as all my comments are now deleted.

Comment: Don't just post code. Explain what was wrong and how you fixed it.